# Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:443

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, port, https, openssl

I am having problems starting my play framework server on port 443,i am using scala play 2.20 and my play server running fine on port 9443 by following command

```
./start -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttps.keyStore=/home/ubuntu/ssl/tomcat.keystore -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=mypasswd
```

but when i want run play server on port 443 by following command

```
./start -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttps.keyStore=/home/ubuntu/ssl/tomcat.keystore -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=mypasswd
```

it giving me error

```
Play server process ID is 12425
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/org.slf4j.slf4j-    log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Oops, cannot start the server.
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:443
at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$11.apply(NettyServer.scala:143)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$11.apply(NettyServer.scala:140)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:140)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:242)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:279)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at     org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
at     org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

You need to be root (superuser) to bind to ports under 1024. That's why 9443 works, but 443 doesn't.